# geom_sf does not use geometry coordinates in axes but plots correct shape of polygon?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, r-sf, utm

**My overall aim is** to combine multiple shape files (polygons of river sub-basins from within a large river basin) into one file and plot as a map. This new combined file will later combine with variable data e.g.(rainfall) and plot by `aes()`.

**My problem is:**
`ggplot()+geom_sf()` plots the correct shapes of the polygons but doesn't have the correct co-ordinates on the axes - it doesn't use the values given in the geometry column on the axes.

My thoughts on what is wrong, but I'm not sure how to correct:

1. The shape file read in has geometry in 'long' 'lat' (`crs= 4326`) but the crs is saying the coordinates are in UTM Zone 48N WGS84 (`crs=32648`). If I try and force the crs to 4326 the coordinate values change as if the conversion formula is trying to correct them.
2. `geom_sf` and `coord_sf` are doing something that I don't understand!

.

```
library(sp)  
library(raster)  
library(ggplot2)  
library(sf)  
library(ggsf)  
library(rgdal)  
library(plyr)   
library(dplyr)    
library(purrr)  

setwd("/Users/.../Sub_Basin_Outlines_withSdata/")  
list.files('/Users/.../Sub_Basin_Outlines_withSdata/', pattern='\\.shp$')
```

Read in individual polygon shape files from folder. Combine with ID.

```
bangsai <- st_read("./without_S_data/", "Nam Bang Sai")  
BasinID <- "BGS"  
bangsai <- cbind(bangsai,BasinID)   

ing <- st_read("./without_S_data/", "Nam Ing Outline")  
BasinID <- "ING"
```

[The two individual shape files import as simple features, see image of R code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mcxa.png)

Combine the individual sub-basin polygon shape files into one shapefile with multiple features.

```
all_sub_basins <- rbind(bangsai,ing)
```

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnB54.png) shows the values of the coordinates of the polygons/features in `all_sub_basins$geometry`. They are long lat format yet the `proj4sting` suggests UTM?

Plot the `all_sub_basins` simple feature shapefile in ggplot

```
subbasins <- ggplot()+  
  geom_sf(data=all_sub_basins, colour="red", fill=NA)  
subbasins
```

The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLl7C.png) is a correctly plotted shape file with multiple features (there are more polygons in this image than read in above). However the axes are incorrect (nonsense values) and are not plotting the same values as in the geometry field.

If I add in `coord_sf` and confirm the crs:

```
subbasins <- ggplot() +  
  geom_sf(data=all_sub_basins, colour="red", fill=NA)  
  coord_sf(datum=st_crs(32648), xlim = c(94,110), ylim = c(9,34))  
subbasins
```

Then I get the [Correct axes values but not as coordinates with N and E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlUM4.png). It seems as if the geometry isn't recognised as coordinates, just as forced numbers?

I don't mind if the coordinates are UTM Zone 48N or lat long. Could I fix it in any of these ways? If so, how do I achieve that?

1. Change the shape file crs without changing the values in the geometry column so `geom_sf` would know to plot the correct axes text.
2. Extract the geometry from the shape file into a two column .csv file with long and lat columns. Convert csv into a sf and create my own shape file with correct crs.
3. Last resort, leave the plot as it is and replace new axes text manually.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The two plots are both "correct". You should not replace the crs without doing a proper transformation (as you suggest in solution 1). Solution 2 is not necessary as you already have a sf object with the correct crs. It seems that your only problem is that the second plot is missing N and E from the respect axis text. I think those are usually reserved for when data is lat/long. When using UTM coordinates there is no need for N and E.